# Retrieve the value of data id through jquery and ajax of one button out of two of button with class upload

Tags: php, jquery

I am able to get the value of data id in the second script, However, the code is not able to retrieve the value in the first script.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.upload', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#uploaddocument').modal('show');
    var value = $(this).data('id');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'users_upload.php',
      data: {
        id: value
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        $('.userid').val(response.value);
      }
    });
  });



});
```

Above script is not working while below one is working

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.transact', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#transaction').modal('show');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'transact.php',
      data: {
        id: id
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        $('#date').html(response.date);
        $('#transid').html(response.transaction);
        $('#detail').prepend(response.list);
        $('#total').html(response.total);
      }
    });
  });

  $("#transaction").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
    $('.prepend_items').remove();
  });
});
```

HTML BUTTONS IS BELOW

```
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-flat upload" data-value="".$row["id"].""><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload</button>
```

Comment: Any console messages?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the button's html line where you are trying to concatenating the value for data element from your php variable.

Try changing it to use single quote for the value and wrap your php variable into curly braces like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-flat upload" data-value='{$row["id"]}'><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Upload</button>
```

**Edit:**

Just realized, you are getting wrong data element in the first script part. It should be like

```
var value = $(this).data('value');
```

Comment: Tried but still the same, I think there is something wrong in the script as the  other button is working

Comment: Thank you Soham..However, This does help in retrieving the value.